# Windowes Batch file: find line with specifies words

Tags: batch-file

I have to run script that find find partition with more than 1 GB free space.
I wrote the following:

```
@echo on
set isComplete = 0
set last = 0;

DISKPART /s .\script.txt > .\log.txt 

for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('.\log.txt') do (
FIND /C /I "GB" .\log.txt > %isComplete%
IF  %isComplete% > 0
%last% = %%f
)
```

Dispart call to another script that prints to log.txt all the availble partitions. 
Log.txt equals to:

> Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
>
> ---
>
> Partition 1    Primary             74 GB  1024 KB
>
> Partition 2    Primary             300 MB    74 GB

now, i want to check which parttion has more than 1 GB free space, so I look foe "GB" word.

but I always get: > "was unexpected at this time." error.
 can anyine help me to figure out what the problem? or suggest me a better way to do that?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch.

You've got a number of problems.

The output of LIST PARTITION gives the size and offset of each partition. I'm not very familiar with DISKPART, but I don't believe the size gives the amount of free space within the partition. It indicates how large the partition is, but gives no indication of how much space has already been allocated to existing files. The offset indicates the location of the partition. So it seems you are off on the wrong foot right from the get-go.

That being said, you have some major syntax problems in your script.

It looks like you are trying to read a file in your FOR statement, but in reality your syntax is attempting to execute a command because you enclosed the file name in single quotes. You need to type `HELP FOR` from the command line and read carefully the description of the FOR command.

You want either

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in (log.txt) do (
```

or, if the filename contains spaces (which yours doesn't), then

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%f in ("file name with spaces.txt") do (
```

Your line `FIND /C /I "GB" .\log.txt > %isComplete%` is attempting to write the output of the FIND command to a file named "0". I doubt that is your intention. The FIND command will print out the complete text of any line that contains your search string of "GB". It will also set the ERRORLEVEL to 0 if it finds at least one matching line, or 1 if it fails to find a matching line. I'm not sure what you are attempting to do.

Your IF statement is a mess. Here again you need to type `HELP IF` from the command line and read carefully how to use it. Your existing attempt has many errors

- You can't extend an IF statement accross multiple lines unless you either use line continuation `^`, or parentheses.
- You can't use `>` as a comparison operator, you need to use `GTR`
- I can't figure out exactly what comparison you are trying to make.

I don't know how to point you in the right direction because I don't understand what your overall mission is. Perhaps if you describe in more detail what you are trying to do, someone can provide a script that will accomplish the task, and you can learn from that example.

DISKPART is a potentially dangerous tool. I don't see how you can do harm with the LIST command, but other commands could create problems if misused. While you are learning the rudiments of batch scripting, I suggest you avoid DISKPART. I would hate for you to accidently corrupt your hard drive because of a batch programming mistake.